# Play/Pause toggle onclick - Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a campaign which can be played or paused. At the moment I implemented the pause ajax feature and I need to create play as well. But when I click pause I want to replace pause element with the play one.

So I have this link with fontawesome icon:

```
<a href="#" class="pauseCampaign" id="{{$campaign->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pause campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-pause-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

and Ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click','.pauseCampaign',function(){

  var idCampaign=$(this).attr('id');

      $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:'/pauseCampaign',
         data:{idCampaign: idCampaign},
         success:function(msg){
           console.log(msg)
         }
      });

 });
```

This function updates my field in DB from 1 to 0...

How can I replace pause with play button using the ajax

```
<a href="#" class="playCampaign" id="{{$campaign->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Resume campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And script is same, just instead of  `url:'/pauseCampaign',` it will be  `url:'/playCampaign',`

Answer (score 2):

You can hide by default your play button by `display:none`

```
<a href="#" class="playCampaign" data-id="{{$campaign->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Resume campaign" style="display: none;float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

and than show it by jquery .show() method.

```
$('.pauseCampaign').hide();
$('.playCampaign').show();
```

If you have multiple button then try with your code :

```
$(document).on('click','.pauseCampaign',function(){

  var idCampaign=$(this).attr('data-id');

      $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:'/pauseCampaign',
         data:{idCampaign: idCampaign},
         success:function(msg){
           $(this).hide();
           $('#'+idCampaign).show();
         }
      });
 });
```

Change `id` to `data-id` on playCampaign tag, and get it by data-id.

Comment: This works, but when I click on one button, all buttons are changed. This is probably because of the fact that all buttons are called with one class `pauseCampaign`.. How can I change this so I can use ids. For example: `id="pauseCampaign{{$campaign->id}}"`. How can I trigger ajax here?

Comment: oh so you have multiple play and pause button on your dom? then you can do with id attribute. $('#yourpauseid').hide();
$('#yourplayid').show();. You can pass id through function, or you can bind with 'this' property.

Comment: Yes. It is play and pause for each item (campaign) in the table.

Comment: Still nothing... The pause button is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

just use jQuery Selectors to achieve this.

```
<div id="myContainer">
</div>
<button class="pauseCampaign">pause</button>
<button class="startCampaign">start</button>
```

js:

```
var idCampaign=$(this).attr('id');
$(document).on('click','.pauseCampaign',function(){
  $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:'/pauseCampaign',
     data:{idCampaign: idCampaign},
     success:function(msg){
       $('#myContainer').html('<a href="#" class="playCampaign" id="{{$campaign->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Resume campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>')
     }
  });

});
}

$(document).on('click','.startCampaign',function(){
 $.ajax({
     type:'get',
     url:'/startCampaign',
     data:{idCampaign: idCampaign},
     success:function(msg){
       $('#myContainer').html('<a href="#" class="pauseCampaign" id="{{$campaign->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pause campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-pause-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>')
     }
  });

});
```

this will set the inner HTML of the container div by clicking the button (once the ajax succeeded).

greetings

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One possible way is to have both buttons in a common container. You can then add/remove a class on the parent container in your `success` ajax callback which in turn hides one of the buttons inside using some CSS.

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

$('.playCampaign').click(function() {
  // Trigger AJAX Call and after success:
  $wrapper.addClass('playing');

})

$('.pauseCampaign').click(function() {
  // Trigger AJAX Call and after success:
  $wrapper.removeClass('playing');

})
```

```css
.wrapper .playCampaign {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .pauseCampaign {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.playing .playCampaign {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper.playing .pauseCampaign {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h4>Demo</h4>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="playCampaign" id="campaign-1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Resume campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="pauseCampaign" id="campaign-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pause campaign" style="float: right; padding: 5px"><i class="fa fa-pause-circle-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```